Filter as multiple combinations in Power BI
I have a database loaded into Power BI.
One of the columns contains long text.
I would like to implement for users the possibility of filtering through a search field that allows the combination of substrings. Example: search for texts that contain the following substrings
"air" AND "tree" AND "RAIN" AND "Climate"
Could you help me, please?
I would like to implement for users the possibility of filtering through a search field that allows the combination of substrings.

I prefer a DAX solution, but there must be the possibility for users to determine the words to be searched in the Power bi Web interface (perhaps a search field).
Thanks!
